# Sequential list with pairs of the same prefix

Tags: python

I have the simplest possible code for creating string with integer:

```
x = []
for i in range(6): 
    x.append('a' + str(i))
```

,witch creating that output:

```
['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```

But how could the condition to create a list in this form look like:

```
 ['a0', 'a0', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2']
```

I tried this way:

```
x = []
for i in range(6): 
   if i%2==0: 
       x.append('a' + str(i))
   else:
       x.append('a' + str(i-1))
```

But this `['a0', 'a0', 'a2', 'a2', 'a4', 'a4']` is far from what I need.

Comment: Why not just add a second line that reads `x.append('a' + str(i))` to your orignal code?

Comment: I just did not come across such a trivial idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comprehension makes use of integer division:

```
x = ['a' + str(i//2) for i in range(6)]
```

It can create lists of odd length, too ;-)

Comment: and in one line, elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

```
x = []
for i in range(3): 
    x.append('a' + str(i))
    x.append('a' + str(i))
```

Output

```
['a0', 'a0', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicating code as described in other answers works well.

Other interesting options include:

```
x = []
for i in range(6 * 2):
    x.append('a' + str(i // 2))

# list comprehension, expect better performance with this
x = ['a' + str(i//2) for i in range(6 * 2)]

# if you have numpy
import numpy as np
temp = ['a' + str(i) for i in range(6)]
x = np.array(temp).repeat(2)
```